# Please anyone can explain how shifter works?

Tags: architecture, logic

[Shifter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnxLz.png)

I want to know how these shifters and more details about it. In a book it says like this
"To see how the circuit works, notice the pairs of AND gates for all the bits
except the gates on the end. When C = 1, the right member of each pair is turned
on, passing the corresponding input bit to output. Because the right AND gate is
wired to the input of the OR gate to its right, a right shift is performed. When
C = 0, it is the left member of the AND gate pair that turns on, doing a left shift."

Comment: You have the diagram and the explanation, what part exactly you don't understand?